# How to group controllers and models in cakephp (3.0)

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, bundle, cakephp-3.0

I would like to be able to group Controllers (and models if possible) into folders in order to create symfony-like bundles.

I'm trying to do this in CakePHP 3.0.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Everything is just a namespace - you can create whatever folder structure you want _if_ the classes within that structure adhere to the equivalent namespace. To be answerable though you need to ask along the lines of: "I want this file+folder structure - I tried and had this problem <> how can I do it?".

Comment: This question doesn't deserve a downvote. Well, he could have just looked it up in the documentation but this question is not about namespaces or putting them randomly into some folder, see my answer. He is actually asking how to package a re-useable "module" for CakePHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to look at [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html)? It's explained [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html).

What you call a "bundle" is a "plugin" in CakePHP. From the documentation:

> CakePHP allows you to set up a combination of controllers, models, and
>   views and release them as a packaged application plugin that others
>   can use in their CakePHP applications. Have a great user management
>   module, simple blog, or web services module in one of your
>   applications? Package it as a CakePHP plugin so you can reuse it in
>   other applications and share with the community.

I recommend you to follow the links, there is a lot more to read about plugins and how to create them and work with them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've realised that the plugins are a great way to group my modules.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this is possible because they are two different frameworks that have their own estrucutura and its own core